# Static Code Analysis to find code outside a try/catch block?

Tags: c#, exception

We have quite a large c# application (1m lines+) and it is highly multithreaded. For each thread that gets launched we need to ensure that there is a try/catch block in the right place to catch errors that might crash the application.

I am wondering if there are any static code analysis tools out there than can scan the code and find points outside any try catch?

I saw on this thread: [Way to automatically see which functions can potentially return exception in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915941/way-to-automatically-see-which-functions-can-potentially-return-exception-in-c-s) that RedGate used to have Exception Hunter, but this product has been withdrawn.

What I'm looking for would be much simplier than Exception Hunter - it would just find 'naked code' which was outside any try/catch, and highlight it.

Comment: You can also catch all exception and keep your application alive. Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx

Comment: Maybe a better strategy is to catch and deal with _unhandled exceptions_ through the [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) event.

Comment: We have a final catch which logs info before the application closes on a fatal error, but I'm hoping to find a tool to help highlight programming errors in test.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if Thread code runs in try-catch block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708503/how-to-check-if-thread-code-runs-in-try-catch-block)

Answer (score 0):

Try Reflection first. For example you can use MethodBody to query for exception handling.

If it's not good enough, move to CCI: http://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/

Comment: Can you explain a little how you think CCI will help?